# Usage of ObjectProperty class

Tags: python, kivy

I Just started to learn kivy and I am very confused on the usage of the ObjectProperty class, and how it takes None as an argument. Could somebody explain it please? I found it in the kivy tutorial:

```
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # bounce off left and right
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
```

Comment: Please add an example of code which you find confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kivy `Property` is a convenience class similar to Python's own `property` but that also provides type checking, validation and events. `ObjectProperty` is a specialised sub-class of the `Property` class, so it has the same initialisation parameters as it:

> By default, a Property always takes a default value[.] The default
>   value must be a value that agrees with the Property type. For example,
>   you can’t set a list to a StringProperty, because the StringProperty
>   will check the default value.
>
> None is a special case: you can set the default value of a Property to
>   None, but you can’t set None to a property afterward. If you really
>   want to do that, you must declare the Property with allownone=True[.]

(from the Kivy [`Property documentation`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html))

In your code, `PongGame` has a `ball` property that is initially set to `None` and will later be assigned a ball object. This is defined in the kv file:

```yaml
<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

Because no object was passed to the initialiser, *any* object can be assigned to that property. You could restrict it to only hold ball objects by initialising it with a dummy value:

```python
ball = ObjectProperty(PongBall())
```

Comment: While it's a good explanation, i think the last point is incorrect, while this would initiate with an instance of PongBall, you are still free to put whatever you want in place, so there is no restriction, and there is an additional gotcha, because the initially passed value (the "dummy" one), will be shared accross all instances, which could create bugs (for example, if it's a widget, and you try to add it to your widget, it will crash as soon as you instanciate two times, because a widget can have only one parent).