# Apps in Kivy: Linking elements between kv-file and main.py and exchange input text

Tags: android, python, class, widget, kivy

first, my code:

main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ShowStartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CurrLocation(Screen):
    pass

class SearchHeight(Screen):
    pass

class SearchMountain(Screen):
    pass

class SearchLocation(Screen):
    pass

class SearchSummit(Screen):
    pass

class SearchSummary(Screen):
    pass

class SearchScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MountainClimberApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SearchScreenManager()

    def get_search_height(self):
        scr_manager = self.root
        hScr = scr_manager.get_screen('height')
        hInput = StringProperty(hScr.ids['searchHigherThan'])
        print "height: {}".format(hInput)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MountainClimberApp().run()
```

My kv file:

```py
#: import main main

MountainClimberRoot:

<MountainClimberRoot>:
    ShowStartScreen

<ShowStartScreen@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            Image:
                source: 'logo.png'
                center_x: root.width / 2
                height: 1000
                width: 400
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                center_x: root.width / 2 
                height: 140
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "SUCHE"
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showSearchHeight()
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: 10
                Button:
                    text: "STANDORT"
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showCurrLocation()
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: 10

<SearchHeight@BoxLayout>:
    on_right_to_left_line: app.root.showSearchMountain()
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "SUCHE"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
            BoxLayout:
                center_x: (root.width / 2) - 60
                Image:
                    source: 'MC_icons_01.png'
                    height: 700
                    width: 400
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: None
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 200
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 15
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "höher als              "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchHigherThan
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    width: 30
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "m"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 150
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 25
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "niedriger als                  "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchLowerThan
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    width: 30
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "m"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 100
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) - 95
                width: root.width
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                Label:
                    width: 100
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "zwischen"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchBetweenLower
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "und"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchBetweenHigher
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    width: 30
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "m"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 25
                center_x: root.width / 2
                Button:
                    text: "LOS!"
                    font_size: 20
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showSearchSummary()
            BoxLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.6
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) - 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height -90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: root.width / 2, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 40, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]

<SearchMountain@BoxLayout>:
    on_right_to_left_line: app.root.showSearchLocation()
    on_left_to_right_line: app.root.showSearchHeight()
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "SUCHE"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
            BoxLayout:
                center_x: (root.width / 2) - 120
                Image:
                    source: 'MC_icons_02.png'
                    height: 700
                    width: 400
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: None
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 200
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 15
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "Exakt              "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 120
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchMountainExact
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 150
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 25
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "Teilsuche                  "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 120
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchMountainPart
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 25
                center_x: root.width / 2
                Button:
                    text: "LOS!"
                    font_size: 20
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showSearchSummary()
            BoxLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) - 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height -90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.6
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: root.width / 2, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 40, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]

<SearchLocation@BoxLayout>:
    on_right_to_left_line: app.root.showSearchSummit()
    on_left_to_right_line: app.root.showSearchMountain()
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "SUCHE"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
            BoxLayout:
                center_x: (root.width / 2) - 120
                Image:
                    source: 'MC_icons_03.png'
                    height: 600
                    width: 400
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: None
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 200
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 15
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "Exakt              "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 120
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchLocationExact
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 150
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 25
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "Teilsuche                  "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 120
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: searchLocationPart
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 25
                center_x: root.width / 2
                Button:
                    text: "LOS!"
                    font_size: 20
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showSearchSummary()
            BoxLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) - 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height -90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: root.width / 2, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.6
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 40, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]

<SearchSummit@BoxLayout>:
    on_left_to_right_line: app.root.showSearchLocation()
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "SUCHE"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
            BoxLayout:
                center_x: (root.width / 2) - 120
                Image:
                    source: 'MC_icons_04.png'
                    height: 600
                    width: 400
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: None
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 200
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2) + 15
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "Gipfelart              "
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
                TextInput:
                    width: 120
                    size_hint_x: None
                    id: sarchSummitType
                    focus: True
                    multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 100
                height: 40
                center_x: (root.width / 2)
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    cinter_x: root.width / 2 + 20
                    width: 40
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text: "'GGipfel', 'HGipfel', 'KGipfel', 'Massiv' oder 'Grat'"
                    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    font_size: 20
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 25
                center_x: root.width / 2
                Button:
                    text: "LOS!"
                    font_size: 20
                    height: 60
                    width: 130
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9
                    on_press: app.root.showSearchSummary()
            BoxLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) - 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height -90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: root.width / 2, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 20, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.6
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: (root.width / 2) + 40, 10
                        size: [self.height - 90, self.height - 90]

<CurrLocation@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "STANDORT"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1

<SearchSummary@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'background.png'
            BoxLayout:
                pos: 0, 550
                height: 60
                width: root.width
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                Button:
                    text: "START"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
                    on_press: app.root.showStartScreen()
                Label:
                    text: "ZUSAMMENFASSUNG"
                    font_size: 20
                    background_color: 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1
```

I know it's much, but it's relatively easy to understand. This is code for an app I try to implement together with two colleagues. It shows a start screen, a location screen, and four search screens. In all search screens, you can enter either text or values. On the summary screen, the user should see all parameters he entered and those should be used to process his query. How can I access the elements defined in the four search widgets from within the summary widget?

Help would be appreciated!

Tnat's all folks!

Phillip

Answer (score 1):

What about if `SearchSummary` inherited from the Search classes. Python supports multiple inheritance.

**Ex:**

```
Class A(object):
    size = 'big'
    colour = 'green'

Class B(object):
    weight = 'heavy'
    says = 'how do?'

Class C(object):
    mute = True
    legs = 4

class D(A, B, C): # multiple inheritance
    pass

>>> print D.weight
'heavy'
>>> print D.legs
4
>>> print D.size
'big'
```

**With kivy:**

```
class SearchHeight(Widget):
    num = NumericProperty(10)

class SearchMountain(Widget):
    string = StringProperty('hi there')

class SearchLocation(Widget):
    listy = ListProperty([1,2,3,3,4])


class SearchSummary(A, B, C): # multiple inheritance

    def __init__(self):
        # SearchSummary now has access to the other classes attributes
        print self.listy
        print self.string
        print self.num


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return D()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
hi there
10
```

More info:
[Python classes and inheritance](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the screenmanager class from the kivy developers:http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

Not only can you then access the sub-widgets on various screens but you can also make use of the various complex behaviours that are already built-in such as the animated transitions between screens.

There's a great tutorial available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx-NLOg6x8o ("Kivy crash course 14: Using a ScreenManager ")

The screenmanager has a `get_screen(name)` method that can be used to access the screens and you can use the [ids](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=ids#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids) to reference the sub-widgets.

This allows access but it's generally better practice to use custom properties to the base widgets (in this case, the screenmanager) to allow direct access without ids. In the case of the textinput you could create an ObjectProperty and assign it to the id of the target textinput in the kv file or you could create a StringProperty/NumericProperty and bind it to the text property of the textinput.

- Using ObjectProperty:
  [Usage of ObjectProperty class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580794/usage-of-objectproperty-class)
- Using StringProperty:
  http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#re-using-styles-in-multiple-widgets

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried that, at least the first part, and screen transition works flawless! However, how do I get a value entered by the user?

Comment: hi there, I think I slowly get the hang of it, but I didn't manage to get it working so far. My variables:
`class SearchScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass`

`class SearchHeight(Screen):
    pass`

text input in kv file:
`TextInput:
    id: searchHigherThan`

thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. If I did it like this, am I right that this would mean that I had to add a get_search_x function for every value the user enters?
I tried to play around with Object/String/Numeric Properties beforehand (see above), but I always got `None`when I wanted to print something to the console. I guess I did something wrong with binding, but I cannot figure out what's not working.

Comment: ok, this is what I'm aiming at anyway ;) I'd like to have as few lines as possible. But maybe I have to explain something: I have 4 search screens (height, mountain, location, summit (there are different kinds of summit types, so to speak)). The user can freely move between those screens and enter values/text as he likes. On each screen, there is a GO! button as well. If he presses this button, he gets to the summary screen, which should give an overview of all the values he entered. These values should again be used to do a search in a database. If I use the on_leave event on the GO! Button

Comment: how can I, at the same time, combine all the values entered by the user?

Comment: The issue is not how to use the values. Your question was about how to access them. Did you try out the two properties examples and understand how they work?

Comment: I tried your example with the `ScreenManager`, as well as the Properties, but I cannot get it working. The problem is me, obviously. I played around with the Properties, but all I managed to do is printing out the address of the height input (if I understand it correctly). I got that those properties work as containers, and that I shouldn't call them as I did, but I couldn't find another way. I'll upload my actual code again, maybe that helps in finding a solution.

Comment: I realise that from your perspective that you're only interested in a solution. However, the code changes in your question make my first answer regarding the screen manager unintelligible to others. Your last comment references only your old code and contains no reference to the methods in the two links I supplied so I am unclear on exactly what you did or didn't understand about them. I've tried to answer the question and supply relevant information but I have no interest in debugging the software until it functions.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I didn't expect you to debug my code. All I hoped for was that there is a simple solution to the problem, like one function that does this for me. I'm glad for your hints! I will try to play around with those a bit, and, if I may, I will let you know if I run into any problems (which should be a bit more concrete by then). But I appreciate your help very much!