# How to prevent properties from being shared between widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a game using Kivy where the player can press a key to shoot a bomb. Here's a simplified function:

```
def shoot(self, world):
    # self is the player widget
    bomb = Bomb(pos=self.pos)
    world.add_entity(bomb)
```

The funny thing, when the player shoots, the bomb keeps moving with him wherever he goes.

After debugging I realized this is because both the player and the bomb share the `velocity` property.

The `Player` class and `Bomb` class both inherit `Entity`, which defined `velocity = ObjectProperty(Vector(0, 0))` at class level. Debugging at runtime shows the two objects reference the exact same object.

The thing is, Kivy properties should actually create separate attributes on each instance. So why is this unwanted shared state, and how can I fix this?

**The solution**

Thanks to a comment by @Tshirtman to the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580794/usage-of-objectproperty-class), I have found the problem and the solution.

Turns out Kivy properties have a gotcha, where the initial value set when instantiating them will be shared by all instances of the class.

To clarify:

```
# this implementation results in the property shared by all instances

class MyWidget(Widget):
    my_field = ObjectProperty(MyObject())

w1 = MyWidget()
w2 = MyWidget()
w1.my_field is w2.my_field  # True
```

As you can see, `my_field` is actually shared between the two instances.

To avoid this behavior, make sure to set the attribute on the particular object, in addition to setting the class-level property.

For example:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    my_field = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_field = MyObject()  # explicitly set the value on the object

w1 = MyWidget()
w2 = MyWidget()
w1.my_field is w2.my_field  # False
```

When explicitly setting the value for the field, the field is not shared between instances. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy's widgets would not do this automatically, probably you've written code that inadvertently causes it. Post a runnable example demonstrating the problem if you want help to track it down.

Comment: Debugging shows the problem was the player and bomb both reference the same `velocity` object, which is created using an `ObjectProperty(Vector(0, 0))`. The thing is, the player and bomb should each have its own `velocity` vector object, which isn't the case. Can you help me understand the problem?