# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.When i run `test.py` then it gives error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in python`?
Someone tell me what is mistake?

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Window.size = (500, 230)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GroupScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.groupName.text = "Test"


class Group(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

```
GroupScreen:
    groupName:groupName

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Test'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupName

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'

        Label:

        Label:



<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False


<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150
```

Comment: No idea about `kivy`. Check why `self.groupName` is `None` in `GroupScreen.__init__` method.

Comment: You don't mean to use "None" as parameter to ObjectProperty. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580794/usage-of-objectproperty-class

Comment: Can you paste your whole error too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to create the object in the .kv:

```
GroupScreen:
    groupName:groupName
    ...
```

Then it is not necessary to declare it in the .py.

On the other hand the addition of children to a widget is not instantaneous so it is always recommended in these cases to use `Clock`.

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


Window.size = (500, 230)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GroupScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: setattr(self.groupName, 'text', "Test"))

class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167318/discussion-between-macson-taylor-and-eyllanesc).